# How can I set default project location for all projects in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm wondering if there is a way to set the default location for all IntelliJ projects, something similar to the workspace concept in Eclipse?

Because I always need to change the IDEA project location when I create a new project.

Comment: If you create a new project, IDEA should remember the last used folder and suggest it next time when you create another project.

Comment: Yes but how can I specify the default directory where I clone git projects, so it doesn't always start in my $HOME directory when I try to open a new one?

Comment: I too would like to know how to set this.  Changing the "Start in" directory for Intellij does nothing.

Answer (score -15, accepted):

- Intellij's Project is equivalent to an Eclipse Workspace
- Intellij's Modules are equivalent to Eclipse Projects

Instead of creating different projects in IntelliJ ( & consequently having to change project locations), create new modules within the same project. Just remember to increase the memory settings for the IDE since all the modules within the same project share the memory space.

You can learn more about this from the IntelliJ [help section](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Project+Organization)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Your answers makes a simple question appear more difficult, previous comment was waaay more straight forward

Answer (score 59):

Required mininum version: **IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.2371.4, built on May 15, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1226-b7 x86_64
```

> ability to specify the default directory for opening projects. In the
>   **Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings** in the Project
>   Opening section there is a new **Default directory** field where you can
>   set a directory.

direct link to open settings:
jetbrains://idea/settings?name=Appearance+%26+Behavior--System+Settings

[image]

more:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/05/intellij-idea-2018-2-early-access-program-is-open/ (at the end)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84622

Answer (score 12):

It's not possible yet (IDEA 16 EAP 144.4199), or the remembering has been disabled for some reason.

I opened https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152061.

**UPDATE** the above issue has been fixed and IDEA now remembers last project location.

Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151727 to have a configuration entry.

Comment: Seriously, wtf. This is pretty basic.